# Azure Service Fabric : how to find the end point after deployment

Tags: azure, service, azure-appfabric

I am new to Azure Service Fabric and trying to deploy the first stateless web API app to cloud.
The publishing was successful and showing up in the fabric Service explorer.

Under All Applications menu, it is showing

fabric:/Application1

How to find the endpoint to access the application now?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ServiceManifest.xml file for the endpoint configuration. It should specify a
port to access the service in.

Comment: Thanks. That helped

Comment: Great. Please up vote and/or mark it as the answer if you feel it's correct.

Comment: So how does the url looks? <cluster-url:19080/<endpoint>? What about the port provided in the serviceManifest?